# Does anyone have any (dummy) fetch url arguments that take some time to resolve?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone have any `fetch` url arguments that take about 5 seconds or more to load (resolve the promise `fetch` returns?

For instance, `fetch(urlArgument);` <- takes about 5 seconds or more to resolve.

I'm learning and would like to experiment.

Comment: There's a bunch of lorem-ipsum random test data generation APIs out there, some of them surely also have a `delay` parameter. Asking for a list of them is off-topic on StackOverflow though.

Comment: Also in the Chrome devtools network panel, there's a throttling option to simulate restricted bandwidth, which you might or might not be able to utilise for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said in the comments you can throttle the connection speed of any request in your developer tools: [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/Throttling) & [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network#throttle).

You can always just pause the execution of your code for a bit to show the lag:

```js
async function yourFetch() {
    const response = await fetch(`${URL}${path}`, options);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    return await response.json();
}
```